# Where are all the "special purpose" pages for the parent site?

Tags: discussion

This should be a CW.  I'm looking for a list of all the "special purpose" pages that may not have links, or may not have *obvious* links from the main site.  This could also include some that are "right in front of us where we can't see them" as the saying goes.

Information for each page should include page title, description of purpose, URL (preferably via hyperlinking the page title), access restrictions if applicable, and directions to existing clickable links if there are any.

Examples of things we should probably see in this list include the priviliges page, FAQ for the moderator tools, the moderator tools themselves, and any pages with other useful utilities or information such as site statistics and such.

Comment: Umm... why'd this end up CW'd?

Comment: The first five words of your post?

Comment: Oh... duh.  Sorry, the discussion below with Jeff got me distracted from the original intent of the post.

Comment: Related Q&A on MSE: [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/335251)

Answer (score 1):

Er.. what?

- The privileges page is linked from your reputation score on every page, and also on your user page.
- The moderator tools are intentionally not linked because they are for moderators only

I don't really understand the intent of this post. It's almost like a "hidden features of X" but I am not sure I see the utility, other than as a "let's make these things easier to find" usability feedback.

Comment: Yeah, the privileges page is particularly not very noticeable.  There's definitely a few, if not more (that I haven't thought of) features that aren't nearly as easy to find as they could be.  I knew about the privileges page by address, but not by click path, (probably would never have even found the address if I hadn't stumbled upon it in a separate Q&A thread) and I've got another thread already opened about the moderator tools FAQ.

Comment: @iszi you get banner notifications when you cross privilege thresholds.. see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/membership-has-its-privileges/

Comment: Correct, but aside from that the privileges page was relatively hidden. If I wanted to check my progress toward the privileges, or check the help info on a certain privilege (i.e.: moderator tools) I'd either have to know the URL or have stumbled across the fact that my reputation number at the top of the page is clickable, and the inconsistency of this between the parent and meta sites only aggravates the confusion.